# Greek/special characters in xml dtd not recognized

Tags: xml, dtd

Quick question: Is there some way to make this work? Greek letters are suppossed to work in dtd files  but i cant validate mine.Whenever i replace greek characters with english it works fine.

```
<!ATTLIST author_awards award (ναι|οχι) "ναι">
```

This is the error i get.
**The enumerated type list must end with ')' in the "award" attribute declaration**
Could this be a problem with the validator i am using?
(https://www.xmlvalidation.com)

Comment: The most likely explanation is that there's a mismatch between the actual encoding of the file and the encoding assumed by the XML parser. Given that you haven't mentioned anything about encodings in your question, which suggests a lack of awareness of the potential problems, this seems a rather likely cause.